# DJANGO - Pass Table Name In Function

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to learn how I can pass a table variable name through a function.  So for example lets say I have a model like below

```
Bio(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

now I want to be able to pass the table name through the function.  So normally I would do a

```
people = Bio.objects.all()
for x in people:
    print x.name
```

I want to be able to pass the "name" variable through the function something like this...

```
def print_name(variable):
    people = Bio.objects.all()
    for x in people:
        print x.variable

print_name(name)
```

I'm not sure exactly what I should be looking into.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
def print_name(variable):
    everyone= Bio.objects.all()
    for x in everyone:
        print x.__getattribute__("name")

print_name("name")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this...

```
print x.__dict__[variable]
```

now you can pass this variable as string. Hope this helps.

Comment: But `name` is a class attribute. Will it appear in `__dict__` ?

Comment: After your edit: Yes, please try

Comment: No, name is not a class attribute. `__dict__` still isn't the best way of doing it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
def print_name(variable):
    people = Bio.objects.all()
    for x in people:
        print getattr(x, variable)

print_name(name)
```

May be this help.